# What is the X, Y, Z "resolution" of a three-dimensional grid of points?

Tags: definition, computational-geometry

I came accross a software which requires the X, Y and Z resolution of a three-dimensional grid of points as Integer. What is a "3D grid resolution" and how do I find it?

From what I understand, the resolution of a function such as [F(x,y,x)] are its x, y and z parameters but I am not sure at all why it would be called "resolution" and how to extract these values from a random list of points in space.

Comment: What software, and did the manual not have a discussion of this "resolution" you speak of?

Comment: I am using this [plugin](http://www.sawapan.eu/) and have read the manual but this is what is written with no further clarification: "Xres, Yres, Zres[integer]: The resolution of the three dimensional grid" These are parameters for the marching cube algorithm which I am trying to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the reply I kindly received from the developer: The resolution are the scalar values that correspond to the value of the F[x,y,z] function. These values must be defined on a grid of resolution resX x resY x resZ.